# Install RMagick on openSUSE 11.3 - gem failed to build its extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rmagick, opensuse

I have RVM installed on openSUSE 11.3. My preferred Ruby version is MRI 1.9.2p136.
I tried to install RMagick gem and got the following output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...                                                                                                      
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /usr/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.6.1 Q16 is installed in /usr
         /usr/bin/X11/Magick-config reports version 6.6.1 Q16 is installed in /usr
Using 6.6.1 Q16 from /usr.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'
```

Here's what I have in mkmf.log:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp conftest.c  -L. -L/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib -Wl,-R/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib    -L/usr/lib -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl  -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib -L/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Actually, the error doesn't tell me anything. I have already installed all basic development packages and ImageMagick headers. Am I still missing some development binaries?

Comment: Looks more like a sysadmin question - you'd probably get better results asking this on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your post. I had the same problem, but the answer was quite easy. 
I've installed the bzip2 development headers.

**zypper in libbz2-devel**

After this tasks the installation of rmagick worked. (Maybe you have to install the complete bzip2 package?)

Answer (score 3):

So, finally:
to install rmagick gem on openSUSE 11.3, prerequisites are:
ImageMagick-devel, libMagick++-devel, libbz2-devel

```
su -c 'zypper in ImageMagick-devel libMagick++-devel libbz2-devel' -
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I installed all the packages mentioned in the rest of the thread, to no avail. In the end it took a couple which weren't mentioned, but which had popped up in error messages - the packages I had to install were tdl and libtool.

Comment: Very similar in my case: `zypper install libbz2-devel libtool`